# Best way to let a remote bot (agent) and a web panel communicate (PHP)

Tags: php, database, sockets

Im in the process of writing a web panel that will manage game servers on local and remote servers. The remote servers will have a simple PHP bot on them that carries out the instructions given to it by the web panel.

My question is, what is the best way (taking into consideration performance and reponsiveness) to get the instructions from the web panel to the agents?

EG: 
Sockets extension?
A memory table in the database called queue that the agent periodicly queries?

Please discuss all options, even if they may not seem better than alternatives :3

Answer (score 0):

Use memcached and a giant array! :)

EDIT

Both sides of the equation can access the remote Memcached server the same way. Treating the big array as a stack of instructions. So the console can add new ones, and the bot can read, remove one, and perform it.

The cons. This is a really silly idea. Oh, and would be really easy to royally screw up if you aren't careful.

The pros. It is SUPER easy. And prolly really fast.

Comment: Not quite the answer I was hoping for, to be honest. Its basically telling me how to store it. Not how the Agent should get it in the first place. (and no pros and cons v.v)

Comment: Haha, Yeah, thats better. The only issue is theres no authentication on memcache, so therefore ANY remote server could use it and put shit into it or read out of it unless properly firewalled with IP Specific rules.....

Comment: And you can't properly firewall it? Or are these remote servers not going to be run by you? In which case, you should be careful about the database connections too.

Comment: Database connections are secured by SSL as well as usernames and passwords. This is a commercial software product, I do not trust users to setup thier firewalls properly, hence, memcache isnt really winning me over since its yet another layer of configuation, another requirement and another set of security woes.

Comment: "Please discuss all options, even if they may not seem better than alternatives :3"

Comment: "All" options, yes. I really wanted to see a few comparisons of the different methods, and peoples thoughts about them. Particulerly the two examples I posted. Memcache would be an adequete way, but unfortunetly its not just for me x3